# Categorized custom fields on Bitrix24 crm

Tags: crm, bitrix

I have around 400 fields divided in 70 categories. I want to show related fields when  category is selected.

Support team can't help with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a software support team.

Comment: Where do you have the categories?